# Insert into multiple tables utilizing pl/sql function results in foreign key violation

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

```
DECLARE    
 cursor curs is select * from starting;  
 appleId number;      
 bananaId number;    
BEGIN  
    for foo in curs  
    LOOP     
        insert into apple (id, weight)  
        values(1,1)  
        returning id into appleId;  
        insert into banana(id,weight)  
        values(1,3)  
        returning id into bananaId;  
        insert into apple_banana_lookup  
        values(1,appleId,bananaId);  
    END LOOP;  
    COMMIT;   
END;
```

The above code results in a foreign key constraint violation.  Claiming that the `ID` field in `Apple` does not yet exist.  My question is how do I make this code function above and have the `apple_banana_lookup` table successfully persist the keys referenced in `appleId` and `bananaId` . As an added I want to avoid having to commit after every insert into `apple` and `banana` on account of there will be ~200 millions records in a given cursor.

**UPDATE**

Schema declaration:

```
    create table apple  
    ( 
        id number(20,0) not null, 
        weight number (20,0)   
    );

    create table banana  
    (   
         id number(20,0) not null, 
         weight number(20,0)  
    )  ;

    create table apple_banana_lookup  
( 
      id number(20,0) not null,
      appleId number(20,0) not null,
      bananaId number(20,0) not null   
      CONSTRAINT "apple_fk" foreign key ("appleId")  
      REFERENCES "apple" ("id"),  
     CONSTRAINT "banana_fk" foreign key ("bananaId")  
      REFERENCES "banana" ("id"),
);
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint  
parent key not found
```

Comment: Can you try `commit` after the second insert.

Comment: @Annjawn I have tried this and it results in the same error

Comment: `id` in `apple_banana_lookup` shouldn't be necessary, as one would assume the tuple [`appleId`, `bananaId`] would be unique...  And 200 million rows seems like a lot to handle in one transaction - depending on a number of other factors, your system may just lock the table.  Also, why a cursor?  They tend to indicate imperative thinking, when SQL was really meant to deal with sets.  Could you get away with just a standard set of `INSERT`s?

Comment: @X-Zero if I do that I end up doing three tables reads from the `starting` table.  Because I have to take the disjunction between `apple` and `starting` and `banana` and `starting` and then take the disjunction from my lookup table

Comment: Okay, I see what you're getting at.  Is the performance savings that great?  I would have thought that using a cursor would have turned it into a RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) situation.

Comment: @X-Zero I terminated my select with where clause after 2.5 hours. Also, that is why I am looking at commit every 25k or so records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something appears to be left out of your explanation-- your code appears to work correctly when the tables are created correctly

I'm assuming that this is how the `apple`, `banana`, and `apple_banana_lookup` tables are defined (note that since you don't specify the column list on your insert into `apple_banana_lookup`, I'm assuming that the columns in the table are ordered as your PL/SQL block seems to expect them to be).

```
SQL> create table apple(
  2    id number primary key,
  3    weight number
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> create table banana(
  2    id number primary key,
  3    weight number
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> create table apple_banana_lookup (
  2    id number primary key,
  3    appleID number references apple(id),
  4    bananaID number references banana(id)
  5  );

Table created.
```

Just to avoid making any changes to your code, I created a `starting` table with 1 row

```
SQL> create table starting( id number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into starting values( 1 );

1 row created.
```

Now I run your code exactly as you posted it.  No errors are generated and one row is inserted into each table.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2   cursor curs is select * from starting;
  3   appleId number;
  4   bananaId number;
  5  BEGIN
  6      for foo in curs
  7      LOOP
  8          insert into apple (id, weight)
  9          values(1,1)
 10          returning id into appleId;
 11          insert into banana(id,weight)
 12          values(1,3)
 13          returning id into bananaId;
 14          insert into apple_banana_lookup
 15          values(1,appleId,bananaId);
 16      END LOOP;
 17      COMMIT;
 18  END;
 19  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from apple_banana_lookup;

        ID    APPLEID   BANANAID
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1
```

Comment: hmm I may have missed something transcribing to hide the names let me check.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table apple  
( 
    id number(20,0) not null, 
    weight number (20,0)   
);  --No primary keys here

create table banana  
(   
     id number(20,0) not null, 
     weight number(20,0)  
)  ;  -- No primary keys here


create table apple_banana_lookup  
( 
      id number(20,0) not null,
      appleId number(20,0) not null,
      bananaId number(20,0) not null,   
      CONSTRAINT apple_fk foreign key (appleId)  
      REFERENCES apple(id),   --this wont work
     CONSTRAINT banana_fk foreign key (bananaId)  
      REFERENCES banana(id)  --this wont work
);
```

Doesn't look like the statements above for creating `apple_banana_lookup` would work. The referential integrity on table `apple_banana_lookup` needs to refer to a unique key on the referencing tables. Here's what it should be

```
create table apple  
( 
  id number(20,0) not null, 
  weight number (20,0) ,
  CONSTRAINT apple_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table banana  
(   
  id number(20,0) not null, 
  weight number(20,0) , 
  CONSTRAINT banana_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)  ;

create table apple_banana_lookup  
( 
      id number(20,0) not null,
      appleId number(20,0) not null,
      bananaId number(20,0) not null,  
      CONSTRAINT app_ban_pk PRIMARY KEY (appleId, bananaId),
      CONSTRAINT apple_fk foreign key (appleId)  
      REFERENCES apple(id),  
     CONSTRAINT banana_fk foreign key (bananaId)  
      REFERENCES banana(id)
);
```

So having this, the below works like a charm (which is same as yours except the loop)-

```
SQL> DECLARE    
 appleId number;      
 bananaId number;    
BEGIN    
        insert into apple (id, weight)  
        values(1,1)  
        returning id into appleId;  
        insert into banana(id,weight)  
        values(1,3)  
        returning id into bananaId;  
        insert into apple_banana_lookup  
        values(1,appleId,bananaId);      
    COMMIT;   
END; 
/

PL/SQL block completed successfully.


SQL> select * from apple;
                  ID               WEIGHT
-------------------- --------------------
                   1                    1

SQL> select * from banana;
                  ID               WEIGHT
-------------------- --------------------
                   1                    3 

SQL> select * from apple_banana_lookup;
                  ID              APPLEID             BANANAID
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
                   1                    1                    1
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this is not correct.  I wrote what was in my oracle DDL with changed names

Comment: if you refer to `apple(id)` on your foreign key clause, then `apple` table `id` column should be the unique primary key, and the same applies for `banana(id)`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR The data is always visible within the transaction, so you should be able to reference the data that was inserted in previous INSERT statements.
I suspect that the error refers to field names, NOT field values. If your gave us a little more details of the error then we would be able to help better.
Check your constraint source too.